# Boost spirit parsing string with leading and trailing whitespace

Tags: c++, boost, whitespace, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am still new to Boost spirit.

I am trying to parse a string with possible lead and trailing whitespace and intermediate whitespace. I want to do the following with the string

1. Remove any trailing and leading whitespace
2. Limit the in-between word spaces to one whitespace

For example

```
"(  my   test1  ) (my  test2)"
```

gets parsed as two terms -

```
"my test1" 
"my test2"
```

I have used the following logic

```
using boost::spirit::qi;
struct Parser : grammar<Iterator, attribType(), space_type>
{
   public:
     Parser() : Parser::base_type(term)
     {
         group  %= '(' >> (group | names) >> ')';
         names %= no_skip[alnum][_val=_1];
     }

  private:
    typedef boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, attribType(), space_type> Rule;
    Rule group;
    Rule names
}
```

While it allows preserving the spaces in between. Unfortunately, it also keeps heading and trailing whitespace and multiple intermediate whitespace. I want to find a better logic for that.

I did see references to using a custom skipper with boost::spirit::qi::skip online, but I haven't come across a useful example for spaces. Does anyone else have experience with it?

Comment: A background on `lexeme`, `skip`, `no_skip`, implicit skippers and `raw` is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest doing the trimming/normalization *after* (not during) parsing.

That said, you could hack it like this:

```
name   %= lexeme [ +alnum ];
names  %= +(name >> (&lit(')') | attr(' ')));
group  %= '(' >> (group | names) >> ')';
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c1c5df7f85e8eab)**

Output:

```
Parse success
Term: 'my test1'
Term: 'my test2'
```

I introduced the `name` rule only for readability. Note that  `(&lit(')') | attr(' '))` is a fancy way of saying:

> *If the next character matches `')'` do nothing, otherwise, append `' '` to the synthesized attribute*

Full code:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;

using attribType = std::string;

struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, attribType(), qi::space_type>
{
   public:
     Parser() : Parser::base_type(group)
     {
         using namespace qi;

         name   %= lexeme [ +alnum ];
         names  %= +(name >> (&lit(')') | eps [ phx::push_back(_val, ' ') ]));
         group  %= '(' >> (group | names) >> ')';

         BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((name)(names)(group))
     }

  private:
    typedef boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, attribType(), qi::space_type> Rule;
    Rule group, names, name;
};


int main()
{
    std::string const input = "(  my   test1  ) (my  test2)";

    auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    Parser p;

    std::vector<attribType> data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, *p, qi::space, data);

    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "Parse success\n";
        for(auto const& term : data)
            std::cout << "Term: '" << term << "'\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Would [`names  %= +(name >> (&lit(')') | attr(' ') ));`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c1c5df7f85e8eab) also work? Or would it present problems that I fail to grasp?

Comment: Mmm. It did cross my mind, don't know why I dismissed it. Yeah, of course that's simpler. I'll take it :)